# Hangfire Background job to requeue failed jobs unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, hangfire, fakeiteasy

I have created a Hangfire Background job that triggers the failed job as per some CRON schedule. I am facing issues to write Unit test case for the same, specially in mocking for 1st 2 lines. Framework used: xUnit, FakeItEasy

var monitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

var failedJobs = monitor.FailedJobs(0, int.MaxValue).Where(m =>
(m.Value.ExceptionType == "My Custom Exception");

Parallel.ForEach(failedJobs, job =>

{
backgroundJobClient.Requeue(job.Key);

});